# Trying this java code snippet , i am not able to fully understand the flow of the programme , new to java

Tags: java, for-loop, continue

I have tried a simple Java code, but I do not quite understand the flow of the program. Please explain.

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if (i > 3) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

The answer is 123

Comment: This seems like an excellent opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. A tool that remains useful for the rest of your career and also tells you how this piece of code is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a loop that goes from 1 to 5 (6 is excluded from it) and put that number in the variable `i`.

If the `i` variable is greater (strictly) than 3 it skips the bottom part of the loop (the print) and `continue` the loop from the next `i` variable

Else it prints the value of `i`

Furthermore, the code is very badly formatted, you could check for examples on google to know how it must look like to be more readable